# "feint" and "feign": Are they synomyms?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Both *to feign* and *to feint* seem to mean *to pretend*. Are they synonyms or the same word with only a different spelling?

Or is there an actual concrete difference in their meaning?

Comment: Is "feign," perhaps, more passive than "feint"? To me "feign" seems more a pretence, a matter of declared intention, while "feint" intends to deceive or mislead by an agressive action.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *feint* (noun) is primarily a deceptive move, such as in fencing or military maneuvering. It can also mean presenting a feigned appearance.
Feint can also be a verb, but in that case it simply means to execute a feint.

To *feign* (verb) is to deceive; either by acting as if you're something or someone you're not, or lying.

There is some overlap between particular meanings of the two words (For example, *his ignorance was a feint*, *he was feigning ignorance*), but mostly they are separate.

Both words come from the French *feindre*, which means to "pretend, represent, imitate, shirk".

Source: [Dictionary.com on feint](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/feint), [feign](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/feign); [Online Etymology Dictionary on feint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=feint)

Comment: But are they cognate? (do they have similar etymology?)

Comment: @Mitch but will they blend? Seriously though, apparently the both come from the French word *feindre*, which means "pretend, represent, imitate, shirk". Going to update the answer with this.

Answer (score 3):

A *feint* is the result of *feigning*, just as a *gift* is the result of *giving*. *Feigning an attack* (originally in fencing, but extended to other military contexts, and then generally) took on a life of its own, so that a single word was needed; *feint* as a verb seems (seemed?) the obvious choice.